# How do I handle the data parameter in retrofit for both the scenarios. The app crashes if success is false and data is null

Tags: android, retrofit2

My API response:

```
{
    success: true,
    msg: 'Custom Success Message',
    data : [Objects]
}
```

And in case of failure, the response is:

```
{
    success: false,
    msg: 'Custom Error Message',
    data: null
}
```

My question is how do I handle the data parameter in retrofit for both the scenarios?

The app crashes if success is `false` and data is `null`.

Comment: You should probably post a peace of code that handles the response. That would give more context, and also post stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Before accessing `data`, check if it's `null`.

Comment: API must send you blank array if there is no data in "data" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, you must have to tell to the API Developer to make API with some structure.

Two ways:

- There is must be blank array if no data available for `data` key.
- `data` key must not be there if no data available.

Reason:
`data` key is giving you array, retrofit gson automatically converts that data to your model class but if you will get null then it will be confused to convert.

> **Key Point:** There is no need to do logical programming by Android Developer

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code for check null condition of while getting a response.

```
call1.enqueue(new Callback<YourModelClass>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse (Call < YourModelClass > call, Response < YourModelClass > response){

    // this line must be write
    if (Response.body != null) {
         // try this code 
         JSONObject reader = new JSONObject("your response");
         JSONArray data = reader.getString("data"); 

         if(data!=null)
         {

          }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually retrofit has no option to handle 2 type of response handle.

You can ask your backend developer to send null data even with the same type for example.

on Success case `data:[String,String]`

And

on Failure case `data:[]`

If you are not using third party api or cannot contact backend guy.

Here is how you can tackle this situation.

While on getting result callback use `try` and `catch` using retrofit exception. To play save with `hasUnresolvableType`

Just find out which exception you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Make Changes in your API 
If data is null the return
{
    success: false,
    msg: 'Custom Error Message',
    data: [] // This is blank array. 
}

if data is not null then return
{
    success: true,
    msg: 'Custom Success Message',
    data : [Objects]
}